# Writing test on generated text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, tdd

I'm replacing words in a piece of content with a rails helper to add tooltips. No problem at all and working fine, but i would like to test this helper on the exact output and because the replacement adds some unwanted formatting i find it hard to really test this helper.

original string

```
a piece of <a href="http://">content</a> that contains jargon1 to be replaced
```

my helper replaces jargon1 with some html to render a tooltip

```
content.gsub!(/#{jargon.word}/i, get_node(jargon))

def get_node jargon
  <<-HTML
    <a href='#jargon-#{jargon.id}'
      class='jargon-tip'
      data-toggle='tooltip'
      data-placement='top'
      data-original-title='#{jargon.desc}'
      rel='help'>#{jargon.word}</a>
  HTML
end
```

result of the string with the injected html

```
a piece of <a href="http://">content</a> that contains       <a href='#jargon-130'
    class='jargon-tip'
    data-toggle='tooltip'
    data-placement='top'
    data-original-title='desc for jargon 1'
    rel='help'>jargon1</a> 
    to be replaced
```

First of all there are 7 spaces between `that contains` and `<a` and i would like the html to display inline in the result but in my code i like it formatted like above to keep it readable.

My end goal would be to build a robust test on comparing the parsed string to a pre defined string. For now i only test on a piece of the string (`expect(result).to include("data-original-title='desc for jargon 1'")`) because of formatting issues with \n and it going to be a fragile test.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could use :

```
def get_node jargon
  node=<<-HTML
    <a href='#jargon-#{jargon.id}'
      class='jargon-tip'
      data-toggle='tooltip'
      data-placement='top'
      data-original-title='#{jargon.desc}'
      rel='help'>#{jargon.word}</a>
  HTML
  node.strip.gsub(/\s+/, ' ')
end
```

This removes any whitespace at the beginning or end of your string, and it replaces any multiple whitespaces (e.g. newline+indent) with just a space.

Your string then looks like `<a href='...' class=X data=Y></a>`, which is probably easier to test against.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Rails' view helpers to generate HTML programmatically. In your particular case it's the [`link_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.7.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) helper:

```
def get_node(jargon)
  link_to(jargon.word, "#jargon-#{jargon.id}",
    class: 'jargon-tip',
    rel: 'help',
    data: {
      toggle: 'tooltip',
      placement: 'top',
      original_title: jargon.desc
    }
  )
end
```

Example:

```
jargon = OpenStruct.new(id: 130, desc: 'desc for jargon 1', word: 'jargon1')
puts get_node(jargon)
```

Output:

```html
<a class="jargon-tip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="desc for jargon 1" rel="help" href="#jargon-130">jargon1</a>
```

Comment: This is a better way of doing it, changed it right away.. but i still would like to use indents in the compare string in the test helper. Is there a way to ignore newlines created in my code / variable value in the output? the added (`\n`) when i indent the html. Thanks

Comment: Yes, see my answer with strip and gsub.